# How to make python NOT wait for my input in a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I want python to be printing a bunch of numbers like 1 to 10000. Then I want to decide when to stop the numbers from printing and the last number printed will be my number. something like.

```
for item in range(10000):
     print (item)
     number = input("")
```

But the problem is that it waits for me to place the input and then continues the loop. I want it to be looping until I say so.
I'll appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Something like `for i in range(int(input("Stop before: "))): print(i)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch `KeyboardInterrupt` exception when you interrupts the code by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
import time

try:
  for item in range(10000):
    print(item)
    time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(f'Last item: {item}')
```

Comment: It works pretty good, thanks. But is there any other way to interrupt the console with like a keyboard key? Other than the "Ctrl+C"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyboard module:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
i=0
while i<10000:  # making a loop
    try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        print(i)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('Last number: ',i)
            break  # finishing the loop
        else:
            i+=1
    except Exception:
        break
```

Comment: Pretty helpful. Thanks.